# How to get a value from a main swing gui form to a child class?

Tags: java, swing, combobox

```
import javax.swing.JFrame;

public class ClickingGame extends javax.swing.JFrame {

 int difficulty;

    public int diffRec(int diff) {

           diff = difficulty; 

            return (difficulty);
    }
    public ClickingGame() {

        initComponents();
    }
private void comboDifficultyActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) { 

}

private void jButton3ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) { 

        this.dispose();

        ClickingGamePanel panel = new ClickingGamePanel();

        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Clicker Precison");

        frame.getContentPane().add(panel);

        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);


        frame.pack();

        frame.setVisible(true);

        frame.setResizable(false);

        switch (comboDifficulty.getSelectedIndex()) {
            case 0:
                difficulty = 1;
                break;
            case 1:
                difficulty = 2;
                break;
            case 2:
                difficulty = 3;
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }
```

then i try calling the method diffRec in another class but it will error

```
public ClickingGamePanel() {

  ClickingListener mouse = new ClickingListener();

        addMouseMotionListener(mouse);
        addMouseListener(mouse);

        Circle = new Circle();
        ClickingGame = new ClickingGame();
        ClickingGame. ???
```

when i try call diffRec into the panel it won't show DiffRec as an option. Any help for a noob like me? sorry for bad formatting, it is my first time posting

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you create objects remember to give them a name. They need a way to be referenced. Otherwise, if there were multiple ClickingGame objects the program wouldn't know which one you were referring to.

```
Circle c = new Circle();
ClickingGame cg = new ClickingGame();
cg.diffRec(value);
```

This should give you access to the method.